# Do all convex optimisation problems have a closed form solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Is convexity of the objective function a sufficient criterion for having a closed-form solution? If not, is there any specific condition that will definitely lead to a closed-form solution?

Comment: No. You can take e.g. $f(x) = (x-c)^2$ for your favorite $c \in \mathbb{R}$ with no closed form.

Comment: @JairTaylor isn't x = c, a closed-form solution? I think I have the meaning of closed-form solution mixed up?

Comment: No, what if $c = .1304234010...$ is some random number with no closed form? It's unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Do you mean you want a specific formula that gives you the minimizer for any objective function in a special *class* of objective functions in terms of their parameters?

Comment: @JairTaylor I think I used the wrong terms. What I meant to ask was - Can all convex optimization problems be solved by non-iterative methods?

Comment: For example, $-b/(2a)$ is the minimizer for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, $a>0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: No, a convex function can still be pretty weird.  If I draw a random convex-looking function, how can you solve it without simply looking at the curve and picking out what seems to be the bottom?

Comment: Algorithmically, a convex function without any special form can only be investigated by evaluating it at different points.  There's no guarantee there will be any formula describing it.

Comment: This question is not really well posed. How would you define closed form and what data describes the convex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are thinking of is the following.  For some families of functions there are explicit closed-form formulas for the minimizer in terms of the parameters of the family.  For example, if we write

$$f_{a,b,c}(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$

then the special family of functions

$$\mathcal{F} = \{f_{a,b,c} | a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a>0\}$$

has a closed-form formula for the minimizers: $$\operatorname{argmin}_x f_{a,b,c}(x) = -b/2a.$$  That is, there is a compact description of $f$ given by the parameters $a,b,c$; and if we know this description, we can give you the minimizer.

But if you consider an *arbitrary* convex function, there is no reason to expect it to have any description other than itself.  The only way to describe is the set of order pairs $(x,y): f(x) = y$.  So it's not clear what a closed-form solution would even mean.